# Searching the web pages for keywords and extracting resutls

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a written a code that searches up certain keywords from a website

When i use `print(url, count, the_word)`, it gives me the results but i cannot transform this into an extractable data set.
I've tried using it panda's but it only outputs the last search result.

```
def getLinks(url):
html_page = urlopen(url)
soup = bs(html_page)
links = []


for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

 newlist=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(links) if ii not in links[:n]]
 newlist.insert(0,url)

 return newlist[0:10]

the_words = ['20gb', '10gb']
total_words = []

for the_word in the_words:

 for url in getLinks('https://www.bt.com/'):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = bs(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
    count = len(words)
    words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words ]
    for word in words:
        total_words.append(word.strip())

    #print('\nUrl: {}\ncontains {} of word: {}'.format(url, count, the_word))
    print(url, count, the_word)

    results=url,count,the_word
    #df=pd.DataFrame(results, columns=[the_word])
    #df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\nn1\Downloads\Python\trial.csv')
    #print(total_words)
```

I want the export the `print(url, count, the_word)` code as a csv file as is.

Comment: Please update your code blocks to make it more readable

Comment: This code not run correctly. please update you code in right coding method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, correct all indentations and save the result in a list. Read from that list and write one it to csv. This is one way to do it.

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import csv

def getLinks(url):
    html_page = urlopen(url)
    soup = bs(html_page)
    links = []


    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
        newlist=[ii for n,ii in enumerate(links) if ii not in links[:n]]
        newlist.insert(0,url)

    return newlist[0:10]

the_words = ['20gb', '10gb']
total_words = []
results = []

for the_word in the_words:
    for url in getLinks('https://www.bt.com/'):
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
        soup = bs(r.content.lower(), 'lxml')
        words = soup.find_all(text=lambda text: text and the_word.lower() in text)
        count = len(words)
        words_list = [ ele.strip() for ele in words]

        for word in words:
            total_words.append(word.strip())

        results.append([url,count,the_word]) #append results in list 

#write result in output csv file        
with open("out.csv", "w") as writeFile:
     for result in results:
        writer = csv.writer(writeFile,delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(result)
writeFile.close()
```